# Simple jquery validate issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to implement the "Refactoring rules" section in http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/

The problem though, is, that I don't know where to place the $.validator code. Right now, I'm adding

```
// alias required to cRequired with new message
 $.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required,
   "Customer name required");
 // alias minlength, too
 $.validator.addMethod("cMinlength", $.validator.methods.minlength,
   // leverage parameter replacement for minlength, {0} gets replaced with 2
   $.format("Customer name must have at least {0} characters"));
 // combine them both, including the parameter for minlength
 $.validator.addClassRules("customer", { cRequired: true, cMinlength: 2 });
```

after the document has loaded, but it doesn't seem to work. Next, I tried adding it to the jquery validate javascript file itself, but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a  look at the [Github source](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) and try using the documented [examples](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/demo).

Basically as it looks, you are supposed to place the code right after including the plugin in your html file.